# How do I answer phone on Honor 8 when screen is locked?

Tags: hardware

I'm sure it's easy, but I have no idea how to answer my phone when the screen is locked. There is a circle in the middle and a green phone on the left and a red phone on the right. No matter what I press, it rejects the call.

Answer (score 1):

If it's something similar to what I have in the screenshot, then all you have to do is drag the middle circle to the green phone icon. To hang up, drag the middle circle to the red icon.

[image]